# How should one punctuate a sentence like this?

Tags: punctuation

How should one punctuate a sentence like the following?

> If she were to find out about our . . . "secret plan" shall I say . .
>    . it would be the end of everything.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid the double [ellipses](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/ellipses), and use commas for the pauses. While I think one can use an ellipse in informal writing to indicate a pause, two in one sentence looks awkward to my eye.

Perhaps

> If she were to find out about, shall I say, our "secret plan", it would be the end of everything.